# Should pyspark version be the same with the spark driver version?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have spark 3.3.1 installed in k8s cluster. In my Jupyter notebook I have pyspark 3.2.1. It works fine so far, but I'm wondering if it is important to keep the pyspark version similar with spark version.

**P.S.:** It's not a question about the different Python versions in a client and PySpark driver. The Python versions are the same for both the driver and the client. This question is specifically about the different pyspark and spark versions.

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail what your setup is? Is your Jupyter notebook connected to your k8s cluster? If yes, how did you make the connection? What have you installed on k8s? Is it a helm chart or some other deployment?

Comment: jupyter is running in a pod inside the k8s cluster

Comment: Is it part of a bigger deployment? Or does it communicate with a k8s api server to start up drivers/executors dynamically?

Comment: I'm not an expert in pyspark, but it seems both jupyter and pyspark executors are running inside the single k8s namespace. It also seems that executors are started dynamically